# Data Flow task error for a source file using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm getting below error while importing data from flat file(.csv) is my source connection and OLE DB is the destination.

> SSIS package "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2010\Projects\Final\Final\Package.dtsx" starting. Information:
> 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is
> beginning. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Validation phase is beginning. Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to
> communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are
> not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or
> on the system's console. Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning. Information:
> 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is
> beginning. Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source
> [2]: The processing of file "D:\Badger\company334563_checkins.csv"
> has started. Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Execute phase is beginning. Error: 0xC02020A1 at Data Flow Task, Flat
> File Source [2]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for
> column "Follow up" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was
> truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code
> page.". Error: 0xC020902A at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]:
> The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source
> Output].Columns[Follow up]" failed because truncation occurred, and
> the truncation row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File
> Source Output].Columns[Follow up]" specifies failure on truncation.
> A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component. Error: 0xC0202092 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source
> [2]: An error occurred while processing file
> "D:\Badger\company334563_checkins.csv" on data row 2. Error:
> 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source
> returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code
> when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the
> failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and
> the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure. Information:
> 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is
> beginning. Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source
> [2]: The processing of file "D:\Badger\company334563_checkins.csv"
> has ended. Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> "OLE DB Destination" wrote 0 rows. Information: 0x40043009 at Data
> Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning. Task failed:
> Data Flow Task Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code
> DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but
> the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1);
> resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
> the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
> MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. SSIS package
> "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2010\Projects\Final\Final\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.

I've created SSIS package to import the data from Flat file to SQL DB using OLE DB Destination.

Comment: I'd focus on the "Follow Up" truncation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check

1. You can open CSV file using Excel and delimit the column in Excel, maybe some data column not having proper value in Excel for example column decimal filled with VARCHAR value
2. Maybe your csv file only has 5 of 11 columns